# Stimul report automation : business object and navigation properties

Tags: stimulsoft

Imagine I we have the `Person` class which have a navigation property named `Skills`  and I want to access `Skills` of each person in the report.

But the code

`report.RegBusinessObject("Persons", ctx.PersonCollection)`

just registers value typed properties of each `Person` in the report and I have to iterate each `Person` to get its related `Skills` and register its `Skills` separately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2959&sid=cf1e9ef4690ddae78032262a574be2b8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call report.Dictionary.SynchronizeBusinessObjects(2) after registering BO.

Comment: I can't find this method I am using version 2010.1.700.0